# How to enable JCEF in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the latest version of Intellij IDEA, but it doesn't have built-in JCEF. The com.intellij component was not found.
What is the problem and where is the documentation for JCEF in Intellij? I only found a minimal example, but not the actual documentation.

Intellij IDEA:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-222.4345.14, built on October 5, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 7 6.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1010M
Cores: 4
Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.javafx (1.0.4)

Kotlin: 222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ4345.14
```

In **Tools > Internal Actions > Registry... > ide.browser.jcef.enabled**

I'm using Oracle's JDK 19 but tried with Jet Brains Runtime 17.0.4 too, doesn't work either. JCEF didn't show up.

I try to paste this piece of code and import classes, but it does not find them:

```
JBCefBrowser myBrowser = new JBCefBrowser(myUrl);
CefBrowser myDevTools = myBrowser.getCefBrowser().getDevTools();
JBCefBrowser myDevToolsBrowser = new JBCefBrowser(myDevTools,
        myBrowser.getJBCefClient());
```

Comment: Perhaps you should define “JCEF”.

Comment: @BasilBourque сan you explain in more detail?

Comment: @BasilBourque I would think he meant the [Java Chromium Embedded Framework](https://github.com/JetBrains/jcef), especially since the GitHub Repo is part of the official JetBrains account

Comment: @cyberbrain Then he should say so rather than make us guess.

Comment: @BasilBourque I wrote that I want to use the built-in JCEF browser in Intellij IDEA. I already tried using jcef from maven. If you look at the changes in the question, you will see the code that I am trying to use and it will be clear what I mean.

Comment: I also have to correct my last comment: the JetBrains account seems to contain an old snapshot or whatever of that repo, ongoing development with later commits appear at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/). So maybe my guess is completely wrong. And I agree with you @BasilBourque.

Comment: How to use it? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/jcef.html#api

Comment: So you want to use it in a plugin you develop for IDEA? (Will not be able to help there, but I really want to understand your question.)

Comment: @cyberbrain I want to write a java application using swing and JCEF. Intellij IDEA has its own JCEF, which is what I want to use (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/idea/222.3739.54/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/ui/jcef ). I have the latest version of Intellij IDEA and in Tools > Internal Actions > Registry... > ide.browser.jcef.enabled which means JCEF is enabled but when I enter the piece of code provided here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/jcef.html then fails to import classes JBCefBrowser, CefBrowser

Comment: @cyberbrain The question is how do I use the JBCefBrowser, CefBrowser and other classes from this package....?

Comment: I didn't try this, but I think to use it in your _own_ software, just don't use the JetBrains version. You have to add a (maven) dependency to `me.friwi:jcefmaven:105.3.36` and follow the [How to use](https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefmaven#how-to-use) instructions on their homepage.

Comment: @cyberbrain I already tried me.friwi:jcefmaven:105.3.36 and because of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164594/osr-and-transparecy-mode-didnt-work-on-jcef, decided to try JCEF built into Intellij IDEA, but there are problems with it too...

Comment: then you have to build it yourself from the JetBrains sources. The version built into IDEA is only usable for plugins for IDEA.

Comment: You can try to fork the repo https://github.com/JetBrains/jcef and build it from sources in order to use JCEF provided by JetBrains in your own project. This page https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/jcef.html#api is about JCEF usage in IntelliJ plugins which is not your case and the registry option  `ide.browser.jcef.enabled` disables/enables JCEF for the IDE itself, not for your project. IDE can use JCEF for such features as [Markdown preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/markdown.html#preview) etc...

Answer (score 0):

Instructions in android studio are:

1. Go to help -> Find Action
2. Type -> 'Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE'
3. From the dropdow 'New' select a Boot runtime wich support JCEF browser
4. Select and restart

I guess in Intellij will be the same thing